# How to add custom folder in submodule tree

Tags: git

I have a submodule that ends up containing solution files and project build files as a result of running CMake, like so:

~myproject/submodule  <-- everything in 'submodule' folder is from another git repo

~myproject/submodule/build <--- the files in 'build' are generated

I would like the 'build' folder to be pushed into the repo for 'myproject' (not the other submodule repo), so that other developers (or me, on another machine) do not have to go through the pain of running CMake to re-create the solution and project build files.

Is this doable in anyway?  Or is there a "best practice" for dealing with this?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this doable in anyway?

Yes, this is Git, the answer to any even remotely reasonable question like this is "yes", but none of the convenience commands are set up to expect it so you'd have to build your workflow yourself, from core commands aka "plumbing".

> is there a "best practice" for dealing with this?

Do your builds in the main project's tree, build doesn't have to be embedded in source. See this snip from the manpage:

```
GENERATE A PROJECT BUILDSYSTEM
       Run CMake with one of the following command signatures to  specify  the
       source and build trees and generate a buildsystem:

       cmake [<options>] <path-to-source>
              Uses  the  current  working  directory  as  the  build tree, and
              <path-to-source> as the source tree.  The specified path may  be
              absolute  or  relative  to  the  current working directory.  The
              source tree must contain a CMakeLists.txt file and must not con‐
              tain  a CMakeCache.txt file because the latter identifies an ex‐
              isting build tree.  For example:

                 $ mkdir build ; cd build
                 $ cmake ../src

       cmake [<options>] <path-to-existing-build>
              Uses <path-to-existing-build> as the build tree, and  loads  the
              path to the source tree from its CMakeCache.txt file, which must
              have already been generated by a previous  run  of  CMake.   The
              specified  path may be absolute or relative to the current work‐
              ing directory.  For example:

                 $ cd build
                 $ cmake .

       cmake [<options>] -S <path-to-source> -B <path-to-build>
              Uses <path-to-build> as the build tree and  <path-to-source>  as
              the  source  tree.  The specified paths may be absolute or rela‐
              tive to the current working directory.   The  source  tree  must
              contain  a  CMakeLists.txt file.  The build tree will be created
              automatically if it does not already exist.  For example:

                 $ cmake -S src -B build
```